# Prove that if a graph $G$ has a Hamilton path, then for every $S\subseteq V(G)$, the number of components of $G-S$ is at most $|S|+1$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, connectedness, hamiltonian-path

> Prove that if a graph $G$ has a Hamilton path, then for every $S\subseteq V(G)$, the number of components of $G-S$ is at most $|S|+1$.

My solution (rough and incorrect): Consider a Hamilton path $P$ in $G$. $P$ has to visit each of the components of $G-S$. There is no direct path between two components so the path $P$ has to go to $S$ when it leaves a component. So the number of components in $G-S$ is at most $|S|$.

This is obviously incorrect. What am I missing here? How would it be $|S|+1$ and not $|S|$. Also how can I show that the arrival vertices are distinct? Surely if you prove it this way, you could have just, for example, one vertex in $S$ which has an edge connecting to all of the components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first point: In a Hamilton *path*, how many components does the path actually have to *leave*?

For your second point: If the path is repeatedly visiting the same vertex, as in your example, would it really be a Hamilton path?

Comment: Surely it would have to leave all the components. I understand it is different from a cycle, just can't see it, could you clarify?

Comment: Also, maybe not repeatedly visiting the same vertex but how about if the path leaves a component, arrives at a vertex in $S$ and leaves the same vertex to another component?

Comment: @user499701 Sure, it can arrive at a vertex in S and then immediately leave to another component, but if we're only keeping track of the times the path leaves a component (by entering S), then there's no double-count, because we didn't even try to count the time we exited S to reach the next component. To illustrate the point about "leaving all components", let's look at a silly example: the path on 3 vertices. Surely that graph has a Hamiltonian path. If S consists of just the vertex of degree 2, what can you say about the behavior of the Hamiltonian path regarding the components of G−S?

Comment: Ahh, so in the case that both of the endpoints of the path are in $G-S$, the path would have to leave at most $|S|+1$ components? Is this all I have to add to my proof?

Comment: @user499701 it's probably worth putting in an explicit explanation of where the $+1$ came from and why you're guaranteed to never repeat a vertex in $S$, but I think the overall structure of your proof looks OK.

Answer (score 1):

I would try with induction.

Deleting single vertex $v$ from $S$ the graph breaks in to at most $2$ components $G_1$ and $G_2$, since $v$ is on some Hamilton path. So deleting the rest of vertices from $S_1= S\cap G_1$ and $S_2=S\cap G_2$ we get at most $|S_1|+1$ and $|S_2|+1$ components (by induction assumption), so we have $$ |S_1|+1+|S_2|+1 = |S|-1+2 =|S|+1$$
components ($S= S_1\cup S_2\cup \{v\}$).